# Getting Error while Launching Selenium Web Driver from Servlet with Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets, selenium

I have written a java code to capture screenshot of web pages using selenium web driver,normally java code is running well,but using same code in servlet its giving me an error.

```
    package CaptureImages;

    public class SeleniumTest  extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException{

    WebDriver driver_rbi = new FirefoxDriver();         
//   WebDriver driver_rbi=new HtmlUnitDriver(); //html unit driver  
   driver_rbi.get("http://www.rbi.org.in/commonman/English/Scripts/BanksInIndia.aspx");

    try{            
        //CaptureRBI.captureRBIScreens();           
        System.out.println("webpage launched...");     
    //File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver_rbi).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);       
    //FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\Users\\srawat2\\Desktop\\surya code\\selenium\\ScreenShots\\RBI\\RBI.png"));    

        System.out.println("Quiting driver...");        
    //driver_rbi.quit();
 }
    catch(Exception e){         
    }
//  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
}
```

}
**Error:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function**

Comment: Did you add selenium-server-standalone.jar?

Comment: @ Debmalya Biswas yes..but without or with this jar its not working..

Comment: Just curious - why would you use this in a servlet? You don't use any of the servlet stuff, as far as I can see....

Comment: @ mylenereiners  i have written a java code by which i can take web pages screenshots using selenium web driver, just want to use same code in web project.

Comment: Yes, but you can use that in a web project without creating a servlet...

Answer (score 0):

You need the google [Guava Library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). As a matter of fact you will need loads of other libraries after you resolve this. Therefore it's better you have all of selenium libraries on your classpath.